# "the" with nationality - Brits

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

I know that we have to use 'the' when it comes to groups of people, for example:

1. The French are good at cooking.

When nouns and adjectives are the same, we can omit 'the'

2. Americans are good at sport.

However, I do not know what to do with a word "Brit".

I'd like to know Brits more OR
I'd like to know THE Brits more?

Can I omit the definite article?

Comment: Why shorten "British" when you didn't for "French" or "American"?

Comment: Yes, would be easier if I hadn't shortened this form. I know "Brit" is an informal word, but  it's still in use.

Comment: @KillingTime What would be the shorten forms of these nationalities; Yanks and Gauls?

Comment: I'm confused by your second sentence "when nouns and adjectives are the same, we can omit 'the'". If that was true, it should actually be possible to omit _the_ in _the French_ as well, as _American_ and _French_ both have homonymous nouns and adjectives. However: A difference between _American_ and _French_ is that for _French_, the singular and the plural is the same, whereas for plural _American_, the _-s_ has to be added. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think usage is different with informal terms and nicknames, in that you're less likely to use *the* because it's not really a proper group

Answer (score 6):

The use of the definite article means that "The Americans" refers to a group, all those who are American.

"Americans" is less definite and may be understood as applying to some of the Americans.

"*The Brits are bad at foreign languages.*" refers by use of the definite article to all of us: as a group we are bad.

"*Brits are bad at foreign languages.*" is less definite and is therefore consistent with some of us being better at foreign languages.

If you want to know the Brits, you want to know the characteristics of us as a group.

If you want to know Brits, you want to know some of us.

In summary, you cannot always omit the definite article without changing meaning.

{I do not deal here with a secondary and complicating issue: discussion of the use of constructs such as "The German" or "The Italian", which cannot be used in the same way as your own example of "The French" as a plural}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. But wait before accepting it as an answer. There may be other useful viewpoints yet to come.

Comment: This is about [Generic noun phrases](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), like a lot of questions we've had recently.

Comment: Doesn't it complicate the matter that 'Brit' is short for either the noun 'Briton' or the adjective 'British'? (Because 'British' almost always requires 'the' whereas 'Briton' doesn't.) // BTW, is there any reason you say "by use of definite article" instead of "by use of **the** definite article"?

Comment: @JK2 Agreed. And corrected

Comment: My experience, as an ardently Francophile Brit, is that those of my compatriots who say 'the French' tend to be saying something nasty about French people.

Comment: @JK2 It's hard to argue that *Brit* can be short for *British.* The following are all ungrammatical: (1) *This ship is Brit.* (2) *Brit people drink a lot of tea.* (3) The Brit drink a lot of tea. (4) I am Britter than you. The noun *Brit* seem to inflect like a noun and have a noun-like distribution, I think.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Right. I was mistaken about that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I disagree; 'The Brits' is a far from close synonym of 'the British', as @Pete Kirkham begins to explain.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Clearly this depends on people's different experiences of reading, and their journalistic tastes. Mine are not restricted to the record industry, nor do they exclude the national press or government sites. Please see my reply to Pete.

Comment: In an advanced Google search {region: US} for "the Brits", two of the first 30 hits were for a snowboarding organisation, the rest for the Brits Awards. ELU prefers attempts at objectivity (I'm not saying the data is never misleading / misinterpreted).

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "The Brits" in UK English very frequently denotes the British Record Industry Trusts Show - https://www.brits.co.uk/about-us .

If you have two British people called 'Oscar' coming to dinner you could say 'I can't wait to see the Oscars' or you can could say 'I can't wait to see the Brits', but anyone without that context would assume those statements were about awards.

Comment: "almost always"? I think not, unless you restrict your interests to the Record Industry. I hesitate to correct you - having answered the question myself - but, for example, a google search for "Brits abroad" produces a large number of hits about the (usually bad) behaviour of the British on holiday. Even the government https://www.gov.uk/government/news/british-gurkhas-and-uk-government-rescue-mission-to-help-stranded-brits-in-nepal refers to Brits as a group. These and other common usages are nothing to do with the record industry.